# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: Azure mobile Services (o)

Tags: xcode, azure, mobile, service, arm64

I was trying to Use Azure Mobile services with Xcode, and query my database on Azure, 
I add the Framework MicrosoftAzureMobile.framework, and I got the following Error, 
MicrosoftAzureMobile

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Azure mobile services (......o)
```

Comment: If you want to add a solution... Please use the Q&A format. Set the answer in the answer section and not in the question part

Comment: I have now moved your solution to its own community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I have solved this issue by Adding the following frameworks,

-AVKit.framework

-WebKit.framework

-SafariServices.framework